# Customizing emacs in .emacs file

Tags: emacs

I want emacs to start with specific settings by default. I found that I need to edit the .emacs file in my *home* directory and use LISP language. However I do get some errors. I need to have:

1. Windows split by vertical line (I work in C++ with headers and source files)
2. Column number mode
3. Cua-mode enabled (to work with normal copy, cut & paste shortcuts)

That's what I have in my .emacs file:

```
(column-number-mode)
(load "cua-mode")
(CUA-mode t)
(split-window-right)
```

I'ver tried coding two middle settings in one - *(cua-mode)*. It didn't work out well.

The column-number-mode works, cua does not load and my window is split horizontally (top and bottom window). Where is my error? Thanks for feedback.

Comment: What version of Emacs are you using? In 23.3.1, there is no `split-window-right`, just a `split-window-horizontally` and `-vertically`. (Just so we're not getting confused, the first splits into side-by-side windows)

Comment: To elaborate on Ulrich Schwarz's comment, Emacs 24.1 introduced the following change: "`split-window-vertically` and `split-window-horizontally` renamed to `split-window-below` and `split-window-right` respectively. The old names are kept as aliases."

Comment: That middle call should be `(cua-mode 1)` -- all lower case, and using a positive integer for the argument as per its documentation (`C-h f cua-mode RET`). `cua-mode` is autoloaded, so you shouldn't need the preceding call to `load`.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I'm using Emacs 23.2.1. The split-window-horizontally made it for me ;)

My problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments to the question:

if you're using Emacs 24.1 or later,

```
(column-number-mode)
(load "cua-mode")
(cua-mode t)
(split-window-right)
```

but if you're using an earlier version,

```
(column-number-mode)
(load "cua-mode")
(cua-mode t)
(split-window-horizontally)
```

By the way, the split-window-horizontally also works in later versions of Emacs (I'm using Emacs 25.2.1).